# How to use resample count to screen original data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a dataset at daily scale, but not all days have valid data. In other words, some days are missing in the data. I want to compute the summer season mean from the dataset, and want to remove the month which has less than 20 days of valid data.

How do I achieve this (in pythonic fashion)?

Say my dataframe (df) is like this:

```
DATE VAR
1900-01-01 123
1900-01-02 456
1900-01-10 789
...
```

I know how to compute the count:

```
df_count = df.resample('MS').count()
```

I also know how to compute the summer season mean:

```
df_summer = df.resample('Q-NOV').mean()
```

Comment: update - I figured out a solution by mapping the resample result to a new column `N_VAR` in `df`: `df['N_VAR'] = df.index.map(lambda x: df_count.loc[x.strftime('%Y-%m-01'),'VAR'] )`

Answer (score 1):

You can based on `df_count` to filter out the month which have less than 20 days of valid data. After that compute the summer season mean using your formula.

```py
df_count = df.resample('MS').count()

relevant_month = df_count[df_count > 10].index

df_summer = df[df.index.isin(relevant_month)].resample('Q-NOV').mean()
```

I suppose you store the month in `index`. If the month or time is stored in `a different column`, change `df.index.isin(relevant_month)` to `df.columnName.isin(relevant_month)`.

I also don't know the format of your time column (`date` or `datetime`) so you might need to modify the code to change this part `df.index.isin(relevant_month)` accordingly. It is just the general idea.

Comment: It wont work. `relevant_month` is in format `yyyy-mm-01'. But the original data is daily: `df.index` is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: That's why I said that you need to modify the code accordingly to your data format. But nvm, I saw that you got the solution already.